# Second router after ISP router for privacy

Tags: networking, router

I found questions similar to mine that got answered here, but mine is a little different.
I want to connect second router after my ISP router (the lan on the ISP router goes to the WAN on the second router).
What I want to achieve here is: I know my ISP can see how many devices i have connected in my local network and wifi because they told me once how many are working at that moment. I don't want they see that info. I assume they have access to shared folders in my local network if I have and if my PC don't have password they can read my files, but even with password I don't want they see my devices. So I will connect second router and connect my PC and devices to second router. All this so my ISP be able to see ONLY my second router as a device and nothing after it (PC and any devices connected to it) Will this work? What router i must buy to achieve this privacy? Do I need router with vlan support? Thanks in advance!

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Comment: No need to be overly paranoid. While your ISP might be able to identify how many devices are on your router, thats where it ends. They wont have access to your internal network. Placing a router behind a router will only cause possible problems and headaches for you.

Comment: "because they told me once how many are working at that moment. I don't want they see that info. " - I wonder why they'd have told you that, its *really* wierd for an ISP to or to pry into a customer network. I wouldn't trust an ISP that took my privacy so cavilierly

Comment: I had bad speed and they said to turn off all devices because they wanted to make speed test and they just mentioned how many are working in that moment. This is  why I want to add second router.

Comment: ISPs retain full remote access to their routers and downstream devices, network shares, LAN traffic, etc. It's why it's always been recommended to never use their routers and if they provide a modem+router combo within the same hardware, to request they place it in bridge mode so it acts only as a modem, otherwise the second router becomes doubled-NAT'd _(manageable, but not preferable)_. This isn't just about corporate invasion of privacy, there have been prosecuted cases of rogue employees accessing customers' LAN networks - data privacy should always matter, especially personal data privacy

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, this will work. A router creates a new network and everything at the WAN side is shielded off unless you do port forwarding.

Do note, currently, your ISP will not be able to connect to your devices. All they do is go to the DHCP server page and see the listed ip addresses. They can see how many devices you have, and possibly the hostname of the devices, but in order for them to actually access files, they would need to do illegal things.

They won't do that, and it requires a very experienced person to even be able to do it (most people at ISP's aren't). But if you want to be sure, adding a second router will work. Keep in mind that it may make it harder to do things like port forwarding, as you have to port forward on the main modem and the second router.

You can ask the ISP if they can put their modem into bridge mode, so everything is forwarded and the router part of the modem is completely disabled. For this, you do need a second router, but that is going to be the best option.

Comment: Great answer! Thank you! :)

Comment: I run a double nat for different reasons. In theory you can DMZ the second device and set a *very* strict set of firewall rules for easier management

Comment: ISPs retain full remote access to their routers and downstream devices _(via network shares, poorly/insecurely configured SSH servers, folks still having SMBv1 enabled for some reason, etc.)_, network shares, LAN traffic, etc. There may be controls in place at a corporate level, but the access retention is still there, which can be, and has been, used. This isn't just about corporate invasion of privacy, there have been prosecuted cases of rogue ISP employees accessing customers' LAN networks.